# How do I use a self-signed certificate from rcgen with native-tls Identity?

Tags: rust

I need to generate a (very) short-lived `native_tls::TlsStream` for one-shot TLS communication over `localhost`.

Ideally the application can use a temporary `native_tls::Identity` built from a self-signed certificate generated using `rcgen` which can be used to configure a `native_tls::Acceptor` as follows:

```rust
// main.rs
fn main() {
    let test_certificate = rcgen::generate_simple_self_signed(["localhost".to_string()]).unwrap();

    // Serialises the certificate to ASCII PEM, does that conflict with PKCS#8?
    // rcgen does not expose a PKCS#8 equivalent that I could find:
    let pem = test_certificate.serialize_pem().unwrap();

    // Serialises to PKCS#8 format in PEM
    let pkey = test_certificate.get_key_pair().serialize_pem();

    // Use to generate native_tls::Identity
    let identity = native_tls::Identity::from_pkcs8(pem.as_bytes(), pkey.as_bytes()).unwrap();

    /* 
    Panics:
    Os { code: -2146881269, kind: Uncategorized, message: "ASN1 bad tag value met." }
    */
}
```

```ini
# cargo.toml
# ...
[dependencies]
rcgen = "0.9"
native-tls = "0.2.10"
```

As indicated, an `ASN1 bad tag value met` is raised by the OS when trying to use the certificate and private key. (Operating system is Windows 11)

What is the root of the problem here? Is it:

- An incorrect use of `rcgen` and `native_tls::Identity:`?
- `rcgen` cannot generate a self-signed certificate and private key that `native-tls` can use?
- `rcgen` serialises the certificate and private key into a format that `native-tls` cannot use?
- `native_tls::Identity:` cannot use self-signed certificates as generated by `rcgen` (It can use a pkcs12 self signed cert generated with the openssl cli)?

Is there an alternative crate that can be used to generate a `native-tls` compatible self-signed certificate? Is there a more idiomatic way to set up a short-lived `TlsStream`?

Comment: Discussion on the rcgen github:
https://github.com/est31/rcgen/issues/91

Comment: Were you able to come to a solution there? I skimmed through the discussion but was unsure what the take-away was. If you think a solution was found and could help future readers, consider *self-answering* your question (don't edit).

Comment: Still nothing I'm afraid, I have an open issue with tls-native:

https://github.com/sfackler/rust-native-tls/issues/233